# How can I divide a column count total (sum) by a dollar amount using python and pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am attempting to count colA totals then am needing to divide that total (5550) by $127,200 to get the cost per item.

How can I do this?

I have tried the following:

```
print('\n Cost per item: ' +str(df.colA.sum() / (cost)))
```

I am getting an error of unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'tuple'

Sample data: Column A has names

[image]

Also, attempted the suggested:
df.colA.astype(float).sum() / cost
The response I get with that is : "Could not convert string to float"

UPDATE:
cost / df.colA.count() The response I get with that is : "2 different numeric numbers side by side [0.0229  0.1233]" I expect to get 23.XX based on my number of sources.

Comment: Please post some lines from `df`.

Comment: Note: cost per item would be sum of costs divided by count of items, not the other way around.

Comment: Print the result of `df.info()` and of `type(df.colA.sum())`. PS: assuming that `type(cost)` is a float...

Comment: Thanks for the help. ColA is in fact strings thus the reasoning for trying to use .count (and assuming i was understanding count properly).
I added a sample of my data to my question.

Comment: in my testing for the suggested above df.colA.astype(float).sum() / cost. The response i get with that is : "Could not convert string to float"

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to remove the parenthesis from `cost`?

```
print('\n Cost per item: ' +str(df.colA.sum() / cost))
```

You may be converting the `cost` into a tuple

Edit: You also need to make sure that `colA` is indeed a column of integers and not strings.

Edit2: Also, as dm2 said, you should be doing `cost/count` to get cost per item.

Comment: Guessing from the error message `df.colA` is probably in string format.  `df.colA.astype(float).sum() / cost` should be tried

Comment: It is in fact a list of strings. I attempted the recommended code however, it still gives and error about converting a string to an int. I get 2 incorrect values when i use print('\n Cost per item: ' +str(df[colA].count() / cost?

Another possibility if it is too hard to convert colA to an int is to use the totals of 3 other columns minus their duplicates however, those may also have values in either of the 3 columns causing an inaccurate cost per item.

Comment: Forgot to put in my testing for the suggested above df.colA.astype(float).sum() / cost. The response i get with that is : "Could not convert string to float"